# How do I hide an application from the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

It's trivial to open applications from the terminal in OS X: `open -a Twitter.app`.

Is there some special terminal command that will hide an open application (essentially the equivalent of typing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> from inside the application)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this is a pretty rough start.

`osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"' -e 'set visible of process "Twitter" to false' -e 'end tell'`

Here is a slightly better example

```
on run argv

    set programName to item 1 of argv

    tell application "Finder"
        set visible of process programName to false
    end tell

end run
```

Which you run with `osascript ~/hider.scpt Twitter` as an example assuming it's in your home dir with the name hider.scpt and you want to hide Twitter.app (you don't use the word '.app').

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly! Unfortunate that it has to be done with AppleScript, but oh well…

Comment: I believe there are wrappers for other languages to the AppleScript API; Python for one.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter one-liner of klobulcar's solution:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set visible of process "Twitter" to false'
```